# GoogleSheet SUMIF text <1

Tags: google-sheets, text, sumifs

I have the following table and I want to sum up the S column when in V column I have a text "<1"
I tried to use the following formula and it does not work:
=SUMIF(V5:V;"<1";S5:S)

When I input in column V the text "cat" the formula =SUMIF(V5:V;"cat";S5:S) sums up the column S

Could anyone assist and tell me what am I doing wrong in formula  =SUMIF(V5:V;"<1";S5:S)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=sumif(V5:V;"=<1";S5:S)
```

OR

```js
=sumif(V5:V;"*<1";S5:S)
```

Answer (score 0):

While `=SUMIFS(C2:C4,D2:D4,"=<1")` will work, alternatively you can use `FILTER()` then `SUM()` like-

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C,D2:D="<1"))
```

`QUERY()` would be another alternate.

```
=QUERY(C2:D,"select sum(C) where D='<1' label sum(C) ''")
```

[image]